# Grails getDomainClass method save()

Tags: grails, aop

**[EDIT]**

This works fine now.

```
def domain = grailsApplication.getDomainClass("Domain").clazz.newInstance()
bindData(domain, params) //work fine!
if(!domain.hasErrors() && domain.save()){ //works fine too, it saved on DB!
   render "Domain saved: " + domain.id
}
```

Comment: render "Domain saved: " + domain.id

Answer (score 0):

`id` is a special property. you can't fill it inside a parametrized constructor for example:

```
 def md = new MyDomain( id:id ) // << won't word, id remains null
 md.id = id // << works fine
```

you should call `domain.getId()` method or if you want to use reflection, call the `getId()` getter instead of field